# pagination is invisible after selecting above rows limit

Tags: primefaces, ajax4jsf

I am using `<p:datatable/>` with `paginatorTemplate`, everything works fine with the `datatable` and `templat`e. I have an apply `commandbutton` which on click renders this `datatable`. The problem is that when i select more than 50 which is the current rows limit and click on apply my pagination is gone. I works fine if i select 50 or below, the pagination shows. Please find my code snippet below:

```xml
<p:dataTable id="claimDataTableId" 
                value="#{inventoryBean.caseInventoryClaimLineDataModel}"
                var="entityData" rowKey="#{entityData.getRowKeyID()}"
                rowIndexVar="rowIndexVar" widgetVar="dataTableWV" 
                paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" expandedRow="#{entityData.claimSelectedRow}" scrollable="false" sortBy="#{entityData.getCaseClaimLineId()}"
                selection="#{inventoryBean.selectedClaimProfList}"
                styleClass="#{tableStyleClass} #{enablePrimefacesPagination == null or !enablePrimefacesPagination or !signIn.currentDevice.normal? 'ux-dt-display'  :  ''}"
                resizableColumns="true" emptyMessage="No Claims found"
                rows="50"
                paginator="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100,150,200"
                editable="false" lazy="false">
```

=========================================

```xml
<a4j:commandButton 
     value="Apply" 
     id="applyBtnId" 
     styleClass="ux-btn" style="padding-top:0p"  
     render="ClTxtArea claimDataTableId faciltyClaimDataTableId 
     secNavTab:processedErrorMessagePanelGrid           secNavTab:validationErrorMainPanelGrid">
```

Please suggest where i am going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: `a4j:commandButton` is nor a primefaces or a JSF component. Are you using richfaces too? Which JSF and PF versions?

Comment: Yes, we are using jsf 2.0, primefaces3.5 and richfaces 4.3.

Comment: just unrelated to the question, but here you've got some recommendations. Try not to mix component libraries in the same project. Libraries like prime faces and richfaces use lot of custom css and js and you could easily have trouble when using them altogether. Also, a4j command button is easily replaceable by a pf command button or even a native JSF one. Give it a try

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried your suggestion but still faced the same issue. I could resolve it with a small logic in my backing bean that returns true if the number of rows in dataset is more than 50 and hence pagination is always visible. If the dataset contains less than 50 it will return false and hence no pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely mean that you have only 50 rows in your dataset and that if you select to display a maximum of '200' rows, then the paginator disappears. Well, that is exactly as you tell it to do by adding

```
paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
```

If you remove this (or set it to true, the default), then the paginator is always visible. This is all mentioned in the docs. Please use them... learn how to create [mcve] and you'd have found this within 10 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My bad that i did not give you dataset information and i am aware of the paginatoralwaysvisible behaviour. The dataset contains 99 rows and displays all 99 when 100 is selected from dropdown. But when i click on apply commandbutton the paginator disappears.